Can ${\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{a}{ab}$ simplify to ${\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{1}{b}$
$${\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}=\cfrac{a_{1}}{b_{1}+\cfrac{a_{2}}{b_{2}+\cfrac{a_{3}}{b_{3}+\cdots}}}$$
For some $a,b\neq0$, given the notational choice, it made me wonder whether we can ever have
$${\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{a}{ab}={\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{1}{b}$$
as we can do with normal fractions. The only method I could come up with was brute force. I assume $b>0$ for safety:
$$B={\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{1}{b}\\=\cfrac{1}{b+\cfrac{1}{b+\cfrac{1}{b+\cdots}}}\\=\frac{1}{b+B}\\\implies B^{2}+bB-1=0\\\implies B=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^{2}+4}}{2}\\=-\frac{b}{2}+\sqrt{\left(-\frac{b}{2}\right)^{2}+1}\\=e^{\operatorname{arsinh}\left(-\frac{b}{2}\right)}\\=e^{-\operatorname{arsinh\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}}$$
Then, assuming both $a,b>0$ for the second one just in case:
$$A={\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}}\frac{a}{ab}\\=\cfrac{a}{ab+\cfrac{a}{ab+\cfrac{a}{ab+\cdots}}}\\=\frac{a}{ab+A}\\\implies A^{2}+abA-a=0\\\implies A=\frac{-ab+\sqrt{(ab)^{2}+4a}}{2}\\=\sqrt{a}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}+\sqrt{\left(-\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}\right)^{2}+1}{}\right)\\=\sqrt{a}e^{\operatorname{arsinh}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}\right)}\\=\sqrt{a}e^{-\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}\right)}$$
Then just set $A=B$ and see what happens.
$$e^{-\operatorname{arsinh\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}}=\sqrt{a}e^{-\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}\right)}\\\implies e^{\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}\right)-\operatorname{arsinh\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)}}=\sqrt{a}\\\implies\cfrac{\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{ab^{2}}{4}+1}}{\frac{b}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{b^{2}}{4}+1}}=\sqrt{a}\\\implies\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{ab^{2}}{4}+1}=\frac{\sqrt{a}b}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{ab^{2}}{4}+a}\\\implies a=1$$
That is to say, no, it doesn't simplify in any non-trivial way. However, I only did this for positive numbers. Is this right, and does this logic look like it would extend to all (non-zero) real or complex numbers?

TeX-wise, \mathop{\rm K}_{k=1}^\infty is a much easier way to typeset these symbols.

We have
$$
\mathop{\rm K}_{k=1}^2 \frac{a}{ab} = \frac{ab}{1+ab^2} \ne \frac{b}{1+b^2} = \mathop{\rm K}_{k=1}^2\frac{1}{b}
$$
in general; so there's no point in expecting an algebraic simplification to hold for an infinite object when it doesn't even hold for the finite objects.

The question was for infinite CF, through. But the answer is still no.
Assuming we have convergence, let in the notation of the original post all $a_i=a$ and all $b_i=ab$. With the convergence assumptation we can consider all tails as numbers and do simple arithmetrics.
In the first quotinient we can simplify away $a$, getting $a_1=a_2=1$ and $b_1=b$. But then $b_2$ can not be simplified to $b$ because $a_2$ is already simplified to 1. Repeat, and maybe using induction, you can see that all $a_i$ can be reduced to 1, but $b_i$ are only reduced to $b$ if the index is odd, while remaining $ab$ if the index is even.
